# Check if an Int value is greater or equal to another Int? value?

Tags: swift, macos

How do you compare two Int values? So, I have this:

```
let limit: Int?
let current: Int = Int(self.stringValue)!
```

But when I try to compare them (greater or equal to):

```
  if (current >= self.limit) {
            value = amount
        } else {
            value = current * 10 + amount
            if value > self.max! {
                value = amount
            }

    }
```

I get the error:

> Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and
>   'Int?'

What would be a way around this?

Comment: Unwrap the Optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `limit` is an optional `Int` (`Int?`) it may be nil and not directly comparable with `current`.  So first unwrap the optional to detect and avoid handle nil cases, and only compare non-nil cases.

```
if let limit = self.limit, current >= limit {
    value = amount
} else {
    value = current * 10 + amount
    if value > self.max! {
        value = amount
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. Thank you so much!